# Placement and coordinate information of a figure

Tags: floats

Is it possible to extract the coordinates of where LaTeX places an item? I want to be able to tell what page and where on that page LaTeX placed a figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) provides `\zsavepos{<label>}` using the `savepos` module

```
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
```

This allows one to place a regular `\label`-style label, this time using `\zsavepos{<label>}` and retrieve the (x,y) coordinates using `\zposx{<label>}` and `\zposy{<label>}`. Here is a minimal example:

[image: (x,y) coordinates of a label]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rhoncus, 
mi in interdum dignissim, urna purus rutrum est, vel sodales elit mi ornare 
tortor. Praesent malesuada pulvinar nulla. Integer mattis tempus mi vel 
accumsan. Maecenas commodo, ligula dictum interdum sollicitudin, elit justo 
eleifend velit, at molestie ligula turpis vel risus. Sed consequat ornare 
pellentesque. Curabitur congue sollicitudin semper. \zsavepos{mark1}Nunc ac mi semper nibh 
placerat euismod sed sit amet nibh. Nulla neque magna, vestibulum at molestie 
ac, condimentum et tortor. Nunc et turpis congue augue dapibus pulvinar. 
Phasellus sagittis ipsum eget mauris congue ac condimentum tellus porttitor. 
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames 
ac turpis egestas. \zsavepos{mark2}Sed neque dui, laoreet porttitor lacinia vehicula, 
condimentum ut dui. Phasellus viverra sollicitudin est a consectetur. 
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae;

\verb|mark1:| (x,y)=(\zposx{mark1}sp,\zposy{mark1}sp)=(\the\dimexpr\zposx{mark1}sp\relax,\the\dimexpr\zposy{mark1}sp\relax) \par
\verb|mark2:| (x,y)=(\zposx{mark2}sp,\zposy{mark2}sp)=(\the\dimexpr\zposx{mark2}sp\relax,\the\dimexpr\zposy{mark2}sp\relax)

\end{document}
```

The result is given in `s`caled `p`oints (or `sp`), measured horizontally from the left of the page border, and vertically from the bottom of the page border.

---

Identifying the page that some label is on is already supported by LaTeX's default `\label`-`\ref` system using

```
% ... <stuff>
\label{mylab}
% ... <stuff>
\pageref{mylab}
```

`zref` also supports this, but since LaTeX does this by default, there's nothing more needed.

---

Since these methods use the `\label`-`\ref` system of LaTeX, it requires at least two compilations in order to be accurate.

Comment: It is difficult to guess what the OP want to do with the info, but it maybe usefull to add [varioref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) to your answer.